# Can't transfer files because of locked and broken screen

Tags: lock-screens, broken-screen

I broke the screen of my phone (SAMSUNG DUOS). Like you can really see the shatter marks on it. But the screen became unresponsive. My problem is that, when I connect it to my computer to recover my files, I cannot access them because my phone is locked. And since the glass is broken and unresponsive, I cannot unlock it.

Help me please!!!

Comment: You need to go to service station, temporarily fit another screen and get the data from internal storage.

Comment: I've just added the `broken-screen` tag to your question. You might wish to check with [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) for some help. There are some solutions linked on how to work with a broken screen (e.g. until you've got it replaced).

Answer (score 0):

If USB debugging was enabled, you can use the adb (Android Debug Bridge) to retrieve your files.
Install USB drivers for your device and the [adb](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979).

Issue the following commands to pull the required folders from your phone.

Make temporary directory:

`adb shell mkdir /sdcard/tmp`

Move files from mydir to temporary directory:

`adb shell mv /sdcard/mydir/*.* /sdcard/tmp`

Pull this directory (be sure to put '/' in the end):

`adb pull /sdcard/tmp/`

Move and remove temporary directory:

`adb shell mv /sdcard/tmp/* /sdcard/mydir/`

`adb shell rmdir /sdcard/tmp`

But then again, this will work only if debugging is switched on.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650407/how-to-copy-selected-files-from-android-with-adb-pull)